# Flink and Kafka parallelism optimization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a project in Flink which I want to optimize.
I have set the the default parallelism and slots to 4 (the server has 4 cores).

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots = 4
parallelism.default = 4
```

This is my configuration to run the task, but the processing time is the same using parallelism or not. During my tests, is taking about 3 minutes to process 30MB from a Kafka queue with 5 partitions.

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fallBackRestart());
    // Get the Accounts DataSource
    BroadcastStream<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoBroadcastStream = getBroadcastPropertyStream(env);

    // Get the DataSource
    DataStream<CollectionMessage> collectionMessageDataStream = getCollectionMessageStream(env);
    final var router = new KeyedProcessAccumulatorRouterImpl(config);
    final Duration sessionGapDuration = config.get(SESSION_EVENT_GAP_MINUTES);
    SessionKeyedProcessFunction sessionKeyedProcessFunction = new SessionKeyedProcessFunction(
            router, sessionGapDuration, config);

        collectionMessageDataStream
          .keyBy(CollectionMessage::getSessionId)
          .connect(propertyInfoBroadcastStream)
          .process(sessionKeyedProcessFunction)
          .uid("SessionWindow")
          .name("Session Window")
          .setParallelism(4);

    // execute program
    env.execute("Processor");
}

private DataStream<CollectionMessage> getCollectionMessageStream(
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", config.getString(KAFKA_CONSUMER_SERVERS));
    properties.setProperty("group.id", config.getString(KAFKA_TOPROCESS_TOPIC));
    properties.setProperty("max.partition.fetch.bytes",
        config.getString(KAFKA_TOPROCESS_MAX_BYTES));
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<RawCollection> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
        config.getString(KAFKA_TOPROCESS_TOPIC), new KafkaMessageDeserializer(), properties);

    // Take lines from file from files
    DataStream<RawCollection> inputMessageStream =
        env.addSource(myConsumer).setParallelism(4);

    B64PayloadDeserializer b64PayloadDeserializer =
        new B64PayloadDeserializer(new BaseCollectionMessageDeserializer());

    // Map lines to messages
    DataStream<CollectionMessage> collectionMessageDataStream =
        inputMessageStream
            .map(b64PayloadDeserializer::deserialize).setParallelism(4)
            .uid("CollectionMessageFilter")
            .name("Filter Collection Messages").setParallelism(4);

    // Assign new watermark on messages based on event time
    return collectionMessageDataStream;
}
```

Looking the Flink dashboard I see 4 slots and each of the 4 subtasks busy to near 100%. Executing it locally and stoping in the class SessionKeyedProcessFunction I see 4 tasks parallelized. What can be happening to not optimize performance?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `the time is the same using parallelism or not`. Also your code doesn't show the final "Finished sessions sink", which I see in the job graph image above. And I'm not sure of your question - is it "how to make it faster" (pretty general, hard to answer) or something else.

Comment: I have removed in the code related to the  "Finished sessions sink", in reallity is not relevant (now I don't have the dashboard but I will update the image, the last figure can be removed). The process that I want to optimize is the piece of code that process the SessionKeyedProcessFunction. I imagine that using parallelism, the processing time for the same elements should be lower.

Comment: SessionKeyedProcessFunction extends from KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is a little bit trickier than just increasing parallelism and expecting a significant speedup. Several things to check that may be causing less than expected performance increase with parallelism:

1. How are messages partitioned on Kafka? You have 5 partitions, but how many messages are actually in those partitions? Maybe one partition is super hot and causes all the work to be done by one operator instance.
2. How is `sessionId` distributed? Perhaps there is a skew there, which causes one operator instance to do most of the work.
3. How do You measure these 3 minutes? What part of those 3 minutes is actually work being done and not initialization, waiting and cleanup? Maybe the sample You have for tests is simply to small to actually show speedup, because most of the time is related to non-parallelizable work.

Comment: All workers look busy (their 4 subtasks too), even the Kafka worker. I have set some logs to control the execution, and the time to finish is always the same instead of parallelism.

Comment: What do You mean they look busy? What are the metrics for the kafka sources and Your functions ?

Comment: I'm looking the Flink dashboard and the backpressure and the busy values look fine. Isn't it enough?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I have all the processor busy, maybe it is indifferent to have 1 or 4 threads? Can Flink fill the 4 cores?

Comment: How is data partitioned on Kafka ?

Comment: At last it worked as I configured it. I just used bigger files, I had one core used a 100%, and using parallelism, 4 cores to 50%, so it decreasses the processing time a half.